# How to handle multiple inputs in alias?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tcsh

I am using tcsh shell.

Currently I have the following alias which I intend to expand.

```
alias e 'emacs \!:* &'
```

I want to create an alias which opens files from a previous directory

```
alias ep 'emacs ../\!:* &'
```

this is also fine, but I want to handle the case where if multiple filesnames are supplied to `ep` it would still be able to open them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why the [tag:bash] tag? This is a tcsh question. The bash answer is "don't use an alias, use a function". I suspect the tcsh answer is the same.

Comment: @glennjackman tcsh doesn't support functions.

Comment: it's been almost 20 years since I last used it.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function in your .bashrc instead for bash, and whatever the config file for tcsh is as well:

```
funcname(){
    firstfunc -options etc etc
    secondfunc -options etc etc
}
```

One thing to consider though, each function will only execute after the previous function has finished, i.e. secondfunc will do nothing until firstfunc is finished.